# Why this statement `priority_queue <pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int> >,compare>pq;` is an error in C++03 but correct in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code fragment declares a priority_queue of type `pair<int,int>` and uses a class comparator and correct in C++11 but shows error in C++03. What is the reason?

```
class compare
    {
    public:

        bool operator () (pair<int,int>&p1,pair<int,int>&p2)
        {
            return p1.second > p2.second;
        }
    };
    priority_queue <pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int> >,compare>pq;
```

C++03 compiler shows:

- error: template argument for 'template class std::priority_queue' uses local type 'main()::compare'
   priority_queue , vector >,compare>pq;
- error:   trying to instantiate 'template class std::priority_queue'

Comment: What is C++ 5.1? (hint: nothing; it doesn't exist)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I'd suspect G++ 5.1, though c++11 standard should be the default for that version.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I suspect Borland Turbo C++ 5.01 for DOS emulators, but we'd have to allow for the dropping of that `0` for that to be true.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Good point of confusion ;-) ...

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I doubt it, it's from before C++ standardization and probably won't have a class like `priority_queue`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't see why not. By 1996, SGI STL was widespread enough to have been adopted into working drafts of C++98. Borland Turbo C++ 5.0, which surely predates 5.01, was released in 1996.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet That's true but only for [Borland C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B).  [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) didn't get that far.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well spotted. Extra "Turbo" in my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before C++11, it was impossible to pass local types as template arguments.

That's why your C++03 compiler rejects the code.

If you're using a modern compiler, you can flip it into C++11 or C++14 mode.
Otherwise, you're out of luck.

---

> `[C++11: C.2.6]:` **Clause 14: templates**
>
> *[..]*
>
> 14.6.4.2
>   **Change:** Allow dependent calls of functions with internal linkage
>   **Rationale:** Overly constrained, simplify overload resolution rules.
>   **Effect on original feature:** A valid C++ 2003 program could get a different result than this International Standard.